# Deleting columns Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been working with this code for months and has never failed, it delete columns I specify and the ones that are not noted are left, but it is randomly deleting all columns.

I tried on a whole new spreadsheet and creating a new script file and same issue happens

```
function deleteNBTColumns() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A:BZ");
 var data = sheet.getRange("A:BZ");
 var values = data.getValues();
 var numRows = values.length;
 var numCols = values[0].length;

 for (var col = numCols-1; col > 0; col--) {   // count down over columns   
for (var row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {   // count up over rows
  switch (values[row][col]) {               // examine cell contents
   case "Author":
    case "Status":
     case "Priority":
     case "Impact":
     case "Owner":
     case "Client ID":
     case "Client":


      sheet.deleteColumn(col+1);            // delete column in sheet (1-based)
      continue;                             // continue with next column
      break;                                // can't get here, but good practice
  }
}
}
```

}

I get no error message, but it should only delete these columns:

```
    case "Author":
     case "Status":
      case "Priority":
      case "Impact":
      case "Owner":
      case "Client ID":
      case "Client":
```

But is deleting them all, and I have not changed anything.`

Comment: Can I ask you about `it should only delete these columns`? In your script, it seems that `Author, Status, Priority, Impact, Owner, Client ID, Client` are searched from all values of `A:BZ`, the columns including the values are deleted. In this case, I think that for example, when several values are put in one column, the error occurs. So in order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Just an aside: your code might run faster if you establish the last row of data (`getLastRow()`) and the last column of data (`getLastColumn()` and then use them as the step values in your loops. In my testing for your problem, I had only a few rows and a few columns of data, but my spreadsheet has 1000 rows; so the row loop stepped 1000 times, even though the actual data demanded only a dozen steps.

Comment: When `getRange("A:BZ")` gets called you're retrieving the entire columns, regardless of your content, you need to specify the rows, or alternatively use `getDataRange()` to get the range of the entire data ([documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function deleteNBTColumns() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),78);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var ctdA=["Author","Status","Priority","Impact","Owner","Client ID","Client"];
  var hObj={};
  for(var i=0;i<vA[0].length;i++) {//column headers assumed on row 1
    hObj[vA[0][i]]=i;
  }
  ctdA.sort(function(a,b){
    return hObj[b]-hObj[a];//sorts columns to remove by reverse header index position
  });
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<ctdA.length;j++) {
      vA[i].splice([hObj[ctdA[j]]],1);//Removes columns one at a time on each row.  Since ctdA is always sorted in reverse header order the columns on the right always get deleted first
    }
  }
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);  
}
```